# unable to handover a string to my method

Tags: xcode, ios4

I have a problem in getting a method to work, and I am totally confused. 
I am unable to hand over a string as a variable for my method.

I call the function even with the string, no variable currently.

```
     Engine *myEngine = [Engine sharedInstance];
 [myEngine getContentArrayFromEngine:@"zumbra"];
```

My method

```
-(NSMutableArray*) getContentArrayFromEngine:(NSString *)catName{
NSMutableSet* categorieContent = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];
NSLog(@"Catname:%@", catName);   
//some more code
}
```

NSLOG output
2011-12-18 18:49:44.165 Zitate[77224:15203] Catname:(null)

Why is catName empty ???

edit1: the complete code 
ThirdViewController.m

```
 -(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
 NSString* myTempCatname;
 myTempCatname = cell.textLabel.text; 

//  NSLog(@"test select %@", myTempCatname);

DetailViewController *detailVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"detailzitat"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailVC animated:YES];
 Engine *myEngine = [Engine sharedInstance];
 [myEngine getContentArrayFromEngine:myTempCatname];
```

}

and in the engine.m

```
-(NSMutableArray*) getContentArrayFromEngine:(NSString *)catName{
NSMutableSet* categorieContent = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];
NSLog(@"Übergebener Catname:%@", catName);
//  catName=@"zumbra";

//     NSLog(@"Inhalt InhalteFromWeb:%@", InhalteFromWeb);
NSLog(@"Catname:%@", catName);


unsigned count = [InhalteFromWeb count];
while (count--) {
    NSLog(@"count %d %@", count, [[InhalteFromWeb objectAtIndex:count] objectForKey:CATEGORY]);
    if([[[InhalteFromWeb objectAtIndex:count] objectForKey:CATEGORY] isEqualToString:catName]) {
        [categorieContent addObject:[InhalteFromWeb objectAtIndex:count]];
  NSLog(@"Row %d has Content%@",count, [InhalteFromWeb objectAtIndex:count]);
    }   
}
NSLog(@"Inhalt Category:%@", categorieContent);
NSArray* tempAr = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[categorieContent allObjects]];

return  [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:tempAr];
```

}

### EDIT2:

Ok, even the hint with the catName did not work. so I have changed my code a little bit.

I have an array with a category, title, content, author, image for each row

I would like to do two things 
1) get a unique list of all categories  (its working fine)
2) when tapping on one of these categories , open a detailView , show the first element of this category, jump to previous and next item in category by swiping around.

For this, I am going to SET the category I have chosen 
First try was to handover in the method, which did not work. 
Now I though, SET the category in my engine.h and when displaying the single item, get the array for this category back.

but again, the value of the category is not stored.

ThirdViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "SecondViewController.h"


@interface ThirdViewController :  UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {
    NSMutableArray* CategoryList;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray* CategoryList;

@end
```

ThirdViewController.m

```
#import "ThirdViewController.h"
#import "engine.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"

@implementation ThirdViewController
@synthesize CategoryList;


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    Engine *myEngine = [Engine sharedInstance];
    CategoryList = [myEngine getCategories];
}


- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {


    return [CategoryList count];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier =@"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        if(cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }


    cell.textLabel.text = [CategoryList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;

}


 -(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
 NSString* myTempCatname;
 myTempCatname = cell.textLabel.text; 


DetailViewController *detailVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"detailzitat"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailVC animated:YES];
 Engine *myEngine = [Engine sharedInstance];
 [myEngine setCategName:myTempCatname];
 NSLog(@"Aufruf %@", myTempCatname);
}


- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}


@end
```

DetailViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MessageUI/MFMailComposeViewController.h>
#import "engine.h"

@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController<MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate> {
IBOutlet UILabel *authorLabel;
IBOutlet UILabel *categoryLabel; 
IBOutlet UILabel *titleLabel;
IBOutlet UITextView *contentTextView;
NSString *authorText, *contentText, *categoryText, *titleText, *imageText, *catName;
NSMutableArray *contentArray;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextView *contentTextView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *authorLabel;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *categoryLabel;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *titleLabel;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString  *authorText, *contentText, *categoryText, *titleText, *imageText, *catName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *contentArray;


-(IBAction)vorher:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)nachher:(id)sender;
@end
```

DetailViewController.m

```
#import "DetailViewController.h"

@implementation DetailViewController
@synthesize contentTextView;
@synthesize authorText, contentText, categoryText, titleText, imageText;
@synthesize authorLabel, categoryLabel, titleLabel;
@synthesize contentArray;
@synthesize catName;

int contentIndex;
int contentMax;

- (IBAction)swipeDetected:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender {

    NSLog(@"Right Swipe detected");
}


-(IBAction) vorher:(id)sender {
NSLog(@"-----VORHER Button gedrückt-------");

if (contentIndex==0) {contentIndex=contentMax-1;}
else {contentIndex--;}

titleText = [[contentArray objectAtIndex:contentIndex] objectForKey:TITLE];
authorText= [[contentArray objectAtIndex:contentIndex] objectForKey:AUTHOR];
contentText= [[contentArray objectAtIndex:contentIndex] objectForKey:CONTENT];    
authorLabel.text=authorText;
titleLabel.text=titleText;
contentTextView.text=contentText;
}

-(IBAction) nachher:(id)sender {
NSLog(@"-----Nachher Button gedrückt-------");

if (contentIndex==contentMax-1) {contentIndex=0;}
else {contentIndex++;}

titleText = [[contentArray objectAtIndex:contentIndex] objectForKey:TITLE];
authorText= [[contentArray objectAtIndex:contentIndex] objectForKey:AUTHOR];
contentText= [[contentArray objectAtIndex:contentIndex] objectForKey:CONTENT]; 
authorLabel.text=authorText;
titleLabel.text=titleText;
contentTextView.text=contentText;
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{ 
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
Engine *myEngine = [Engine sharedInstance];
contentArray = [myEngine getContentArrayFromEngine];
contentMax = [contentArray count];


UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRecognizerRight = 
[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]
 initWithTarget:self 
 action:@selector(vorher:)];
swipeRecognizerRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeRecognizerRight];

UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRecognizerLeft = 
[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]
 initWithTarget:self 
 action:@selector(nachher:)];
swipeRecognizerLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeRecognizerLeft];

titleText = [[contentArray objectAtIndex:contentIndex] objectForKey:TITLE];
authorText= [[contentArray objectAtIndex:contentIndex] objectForKey:AUTHOR];
contentText= [[contentArray objectAtIndex:contentIndex] objectForKey:CONTENT]; 
authorLabel.text=authorText;
titleLabel.text=titleText;
contentTextView.text=contentText;    
}


- (void)viewDidUnload
{
[super viewDidUnload];
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
// e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
// Return YES for supported orientations
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

@end
```

engine.h

```
//#import 

#define AUTHOR  @"author"
#define CATEGORY  @"cat"
#define CONTENT  @"content"
#define IMAGE @"image"
#define TITLE @"title"


@interface Engine : NSObject {
        NSMutableArray* InhalteFromWeb;
    NSInteger maxAnzahlInhalte;
    NSString* categNameStorage;
}

+ (Engine *) sharedInstance;

- (NSMutableArray*) getZitateArrayFromEngine;
- (NSInteger) getMaxAnzahlZitateFromEngine;

- (NSString*) getAutor:(NSInteger)pos;
- (NSString*) getZitat:(NSInteger)pos;

- (NSString*) getAuthor:(NSInteger)pos;
- (NSString*) getCategory:(NSInteger)pos;
- (NSString*) getContent:(NSInteger)pos;
- (NSString*) getImage:(NSInteger)pos;
- (NSString*) getTitle:(NSInteger)pos;

-(NSMutableArray*) getContentArrayFromEngine;
-(void) setCategName:(NSString *) categNameVariable;
-(NSString*) getCategName;

-(NSMutableArray*) getCategories;

@end
```

engine.m

```
#import "Engine.h"

@implementation Engine

static Engine *_sharedInstance;

- (id) init
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        // custom initialization

        //Beginn my code
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.*/iMotivate.plist"];
        NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

        NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];

        if( theConnection )
        {

            InhalteFromWeb = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
            maxAnzahlInhalte = [InhalteFromWeb count];
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Connection failed");
        }
    }
    return self;
}


-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
  //  NSLog(@"Recieving Response...");
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{

 //   NSLog(@"Recieving Data...");

}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                   message : @"An error has occured.Please verify your internet connection."
                                                   delegate:nil
                                         cancelButtonTitle :@"OK"
                                         otherButtonTitles :nil];
    [alert show];



}
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{

  //  NSLog(@"DONE. Received Quotes: %d", maxAnzahlZitate);
}




// ###########

+ (Engine *) sharedInstance
{
    if (!_sharedInstance)
    {
        _sharedInstance = [[Engine alloc] init];
    }

    return _sharedInstance;
}

// Getter and Setter for WebArray
- (NSMutableArray*) getZitateArrayFromEngine{
    return InhalteFromWeb;

}
- (NSInteger) getMaxAnzahlZitateFromEngine{
    return maxAnzahlInhalte;
}

- (NSString*) getAutor:(NSInteger)pos{
    return [[InhalteFromWeb objectAtIndex:pos] objectForKey:AUTHOR];

}
- (NSString*) getZitat:(NSInteger)pos{
    return [[InhalteFromWeb objectAtIndex:pos] objectForKey:CONTENT];
}

// #######

- (NSString*) getAuthor:(NSInteger)pos{
    return [[InhalteFromWeb objectAtIndex:pos] objectForKey:AUTHOR];

}

- (NSString*) getCategory:(NSInteger)pos{
    return [[InhalteFromWeb objectAtIndex:pos] objectForKey:CATEGORY];

}

- (NSString*) getContent:(NSInteger)pos{
    return [[InhalteFromWeb objectAtIndex:pos] objectForKey:CONTENT];

}

- (NSString*) getImage:(NSInteger)pos{
    return [[InhalteFromWeb objectAtIndex:pos] objectForKey:IMAGE];

}
- (NSString*) getTitle:(NSInteger)pos{
    return [[InhalteFromWeb objectAtIndex:pos] objectForKey:TITLE];

}

-(NSArray*) getCategories {
    NSMutableSet* categorieSet = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];

    unsigned count = [InhalteFromWeb count];
    while (count--) {
        NSString *tempString;
        tempString=[[InhalteFromWeb objectAtIndex:count] objectForKey:CATEGORY];
  //      NSLog(@"tempString %@", tempString );

        [categorieSet addObject:tempString];
    }
 //   NSLog(@"categories from engine %@", categorieSet);
    NSArray* tempAr = [[[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[categorieSet allObjects]]sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];

    return  [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:tempAr];

}

-(void) setCategName:(NSString *) categNameVariable
{   NSLog(@"categNameStorage 2%@",categNameStorage);
    categNameStorage=categNameVariable;
    NSLog(@"setCategName 1 %@",categNameVariable);
    NSLog(@"categNameStorage 2%@",categNameStorage);
}

-(NSString*) getCategName {
    return categNameStorage;
}



-(NSMutableArray*) getContentArrayFromEngine{
    NSMutableSet* categorieContent = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"Übergebener Catname:%@", categNameStorage);  
   //     NSLog(@"Inhalt InhalteFromWeb:%@", InhalteFromWeb);


    unsigned count = [InhalteFromWeb count];
    while (count--) {
 //       NSLog(@"count %d %@", count, [[InhalteFromWeb objectAtIndex:count] objectForKey:CATEGORY]);
        if([[[InhalteFromWeb objectAtIndex:count] objectForKey:CATEGORY] isEqualToString:categNameStorage]) {
            [categorieContent addObject:[InhalteFromWeb objectAtIndex:count]];
 //     NSLog(@"Row %d has Content%@",count, [InhalteFromWeb objectAtIndex:count]);
        }   
    }
 //   NSLog(@"Inhalt Category:%@", categorieContent);
    NSArray* tempAr = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[categorieContent allObjects]];

    return  [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:tempAr];
}


@end
```

Comment: As it stand this code should log zumbra as you expect. There must be something missing from the question...

Comment: have added the complete code .... it is not working, until I set the catName directly to a value in getContentArrayFromEngine

Comment: Is catName by any chance an instance variable in your engine class? If you change the name of the variable in your argument, does it work?

Comment: No, this was not the case. I have now inserted all relevant 6 files. I am completely lost now, what is going wrong. I do not understand the reason, why I do not get this variable set, even if using a "global variable" in my engine.h

Comment: Is cell.textLabel.text empty or does it give you the value you want? You should step through this with the debugger, and find the exact point that it fails. Narrow it down to the simplest case that fails. It's not helpful to post your entire codebase.

Answer (score 0):

There has to be a variable conflict with 'catName' in your view controller. I'm not sure why the view controller would be in scope, but I bet if you change your parameter to "inCatName" it will be fine. It's good to use naming conventions like that for this reason.